# What material is used on the ISS for conducting electricity?

Tags: iss

Got a million questions, this is the first.

Comment: Welcome at Space.SE! Please look at the [tour](https://space.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help](https://space.stackexchange.com/help) pages to see what kind of question can be asked here and how good questions look like. The image seems unrelated to your question, so I recommend removing it. Furthermore, they body of the question should elaborate on the title, as it is its just fluff that can (and should) be removed since it has no informational value.

Comment: I think it is copper. Although they may have spared some hundreds of kg of launch mass, if they had used silver.

Comment: If we compare conductivity per weight, aluminium is better than copper.

Comment: The question doesn't need much explanation, but the image is out place. If you register for the site, you can put information about yourself on your profile page. I'm just guessing that maybe that was your intention. Welcome to Space.SE.

Answer (score 8):

Dedicated current and signal paths are created using copper cables of various configurations, depending on use case (simple stranded, twisted-shielded pair, coax, etc.)

The ISS structure, made generally of 2219 aluminum (and a few other alloys here and there) is held at a common ground potential as well via dedicated electrical bonds from piece to piece.  This is not an intended return path but instead exists to provide a return path for electrical faults and to ensure that interaction with the LEO plasma environment does not create dangerous potentials between hardware elements that could injure EVA crewmembers or damage sensitive hardware.

To address a comment to the question: silver is not used on ISS, as it is not compatible with the atomic oxygen environment in LEO.  Exposed silver will be continually oxidized, and (unlike metals like aluminum) the silver oxide will spall away, eventually eroding away all of the silver.